# Use %%s% in a SQL statement of a MySQLdb cursor

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I want to select data from my database where the `COLUMN_NAME` value contains a string, an example is below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE LOWER('%foobar%')
```

The above SQL statement should select from the table `mytable` where `COLUMN_NAME` contains `foobar` (incase sensitive)

However `foobar` was an example and I'm not sure how to implement this in a Python MySQLdb query while escaping the value which will be put instead of `foobar`

I have tried the following but it seems their syntax is incorrect:

```py
value = "foobar"
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE LOWER('%%s%')", (value,))
```

```py
value = "foobar"
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE LOWER(%%s%)", (value,))
```

```py
value = "foobar"
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE LOWER('% %s %')", (value,))
```

Any help on how to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parameterized queries that use the percent symbol, `%` , parameter value should include the wildcards which you can interpolate with F-string:

```py
# VALUE WITH WILDCARDS
value = "foobar"
param = f"%{value}%"

# PREPARED STATEMENT WITHOUT QUOTES
sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE LOWER(%s)"

# EXECUTE AND BIND PARAM
cursor.execute(sql, (param,))
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I have not tested this with MySQLdb, but usually you can escape the `%` in format-strings by doubling it.

Therefor

```
value = "foobar"
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE LOWER('%%%s%%')", (value,))
```

should work.

---

**UPDATE:**

My proposed solution doesn't work, because the query is prepared with [`mogrify()`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/6ccbecc1a0dfd04065b081950d2d35b1dac0aaa8/pymysql/cursors.py#L105-L136) which uses [`literal()`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/6ccbecc1a0dfd04065b081950d2d35b1dac0aaa8/pymysql/connections.py#L497-L516).
`literal` always adds the single quotes `'`. So the query becomes  `LOWER('%'foobar'%')` and is invalid.

Please Consider [Parfait's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67779701/3749896).

Comment: This made it `LOWER(%'foobar'%)` while it should be `LOWER('%foobar%')`

Comment: I copied the second one from the question where the quotes were missing... I think that (edit) should do it now, right?

Comment: It's actually `LOWER('%'foobar'%')` now. Would be lit if I can get rid of the quotes between `foobar`. I can make it `LOWER("%%%s%%")` to get it working but it will look for `'foobar'` while I want it to look for `foobar`

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not read correctly. I am afraid that is not possible. Give me some more time to check this and update my answer with an explanation.

Comment: I thought so. Do you think using `MySQLdb.escape_string()` for this bit would be enough

Comment: @Mario I got my answer correctly. `%` can be parameterized here without any problems. Sorry for the circumstances, I have now also learned something.